# Refinery CMS replace model layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, refinerycms

I have a situation in which I want to replace my **model layer** (Activerecord) generated by a **Refinery CMS** engine with API calls that will return data to me in JSON. Is it possible? if yes please guide me to some tutorial/demo.

Comment: check this out its having full description about Extending Models with Decorators http://refinerycms.com/guides/extending-models

Comment: Actually I am trying to replace the Activerecord layer altogether, rather than extending it.

Comment: Anyone with other ideas as extending models does not seem to be the solution for my scenario.